# If $ax + by ≤ bx + cy ≤ cx + ay$ then $b ≤ c$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Let $a, b, c, x, y$ be positive real numbers such that
>   $$ax + by ≤ bx + cy ≤ cx + ay$$
>   Prove that $b ≤ c$.

As of now I did simple algebraic manipulation:  I just put all the $a$'s on one side the $b$'s in the middle and $c$'s last and then crossed out the $(x-y)$ but I doubt that this approach is correct. 
Can someone provide a solution to this.

Comment: What was your manipulation and what was its result?

Comment: This is a current [USAMTS problem](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)

Comment: USAMTS is a competition and the user calcstar is violating the rules of competition.  The moderators on Stackexchange have to disable these activities in future.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii: Please flag these when you see them.

Comment: @KirthiRaman: Ditto.

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round Two problem set ([problem 2](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 8 Dec 2014.

Comment: Assume the contrary then everything is fine. If $b> c$ then by second ineq. $a>c$ then compare first and third to get $a>b$ then the first ineq is impossible, contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Since the required conclusion does not involve $a$, let's try to get rid of it.  We have
$$bx+cy-cx\le ay\quad\hbox{and}\quad ax\le bx+cy-by$$
and so, remembering that $x$ and $y$ are positive,
$$(bx+cy-cx)x\le axy\le (bx+cy-by)y\ .$$
Therefore
$$(bx+cy-cx)x\le (bx+cy-by)y\ ;$$
rearranging gives
$$b(x^2-xy+y^2)\le c(x^2-xy+y^2)$$
and now there is only one thing you still need to prove.  Can you do it?

Comment: Apparently it was forgotten to undelete your answer when the question was unlocked. Apologies for that.